# How to compile OpenMP and MPI hybrid C program on OS X

Tags: c, multithreading, macos, parallel-processing

I was testing a HelloWorld C program that mixes OpenMP and MPI on my Macbook Pro.

Compiling with `mpicc -fopenmp helloworld.c -o helloworld` or `mpicc -openmp helloworld.c -o helloworld` both give me an error message `fatal error: 'omp.h' file not found`.

If I compile only the MPI part with `mpicc helloworld.c -o helloworld`, or only the OpenMP part with `gcc -fopenmp helloworld.c -o helloworld`, it worked just fine.

I looked up in SO and I've seen people successfully compile in Linux so I was wondering if this is an issue for OS X only. Should I use a different flag for OS X other than `-openmp` or `-fopenmp`? I am using OpenMPI-1.10.0 with OS X El Capitan (10.11.1).

The simple HelloWorld program code is given as below and the steps I followed is on [this page](http://www.slac.stanford.edu/comp/unix/farm/mpi_and_openmp.html):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "mpi.h"
#include <omp.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  int numprocs, rank, namelen;
  char processor_name[MPI_MAX_PROCESSOR_NAME];
  int iam = 0, np = 1;

  MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
  MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &numprocs);
  MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
  MPI_Get_processor_name(processor_name, &namelen);

  #pragma omp parallel default(shared) private(iam, np)
  {
    np = omp_get_num_threads();
    iam = omp_get_thread_num();
    printf("Hello from thread %d out of %d from process %d out of %d on %s\n",
           iam, np, rank, numprocs, processor_name);
  }

  MPI_Finalize();
}
```

Comment: compile openmp first, link with mpi later

Comment: @user3528438 Thanks for your reply. Can you be more specific?

Comment: since the `omp.h` file is not being found at compile time, add the `-IpathTo_omp.h_File` to the compile statement

Comment: @user3629249 Thanks for the help. I was able to compile and run it after specifying the include path as you suggested. But I couldn't compile it directly with `mpicc`, instead I used `-showme` flag with `mpicc` and it generated a compiling command line with `gcc` followed by `-lmpi`. I was able to compile the program with that one only.

Answer (score 1):

I just use:

```
#include "/usr/local/opt/llvm/lib/clang/3.8.1/include/omp.h"
```

and compile with

```
mpicc -openmp main.c
```

Comment: Doesn't work. The compiler will assume that _-o_ is setting your output filename to _penmp_.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
mpicc -qopenmp -o prog prog.c
```